# Comment flood per post

Tags: php, wordpress

i found this code in the wp docs to change the number of seconds for the flood filter message to appear:

```
    function wpdocs_dam_the_flood( $dam_it, $time_last, $time_new ) {
    if ( ( $time_new - $time_last ) < 300 ) { // time interval is 300 seconds
        return true;
    }
 
    return false;
}
add_filter( 'comment_flood_filter', 'wpdocs_dam_the_flood', 10, 3 );
```

Now e.g. i want that the user have to wait 300 seconds long after commenting once to comment again (that's what the code is doing) BUT only on the same post. The function with the changed flood time should not apply for all posts but only to the current one he commented.

Can someone help me updating the code for this purpose?

Comment: Well, according to its [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_flood_filter/) the `comment_flood_filter` hook doesn't know where the comment is being added to so looks like you'll need to use a different approach here.

Comment: Check out the action `pre_comment_on_post` which includes the post ID. It will be your responsibility of performing most of the logic, however.